# How to align a paragraph in the middle of the div?

Tags: html, css, angular, alignment, boilerplate

Using a couple of Angular containers I want to align in the middle of the cells the text. Unfortunately the vertical align doesn't work.

Hereby the code:

```css
main {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 6%;
  padding-left: 7%;
  padding-right: 7%;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.vertical-align {
  height: 100%;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="vertical-align">
    <p>{{ data.text}}</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Do you have any idea how I could fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vertical align doesn't work with block elements. `p` tag is a block element

In order to center vertically you need to use flexbox

```
.vertical-align {
  height: 100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

Refer example below, Also not that I changed the height of the main container from 100% to 100vh just for the sake of the example

```css
main {
  height: 100vh;/*for example purpose*/
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 6%;
  padding-left: 7%;
  padding-right: 7%;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.vertical-align {
  height: 100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  border:1px solid red;/*for example purpose*/
}

p {
  position: relative;
  /*vertical-align: middle;*/
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="vertical-align">
    <p>lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem </p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple example on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_center-vertical.asp) on how to center vertically and horizontally using position & transform.

Here is a working example.

```css
.center { 
  height: 100vh; /* 100vh is used for fullscreen, set your div height here instead. */
  position: relative;
}

.center p {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="center">
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer basic html css reference

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<div class="flex-container">
  <p>Content in center</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

https://codepen.io/samuveljohns/pen/JjPWEVz

Answer (score 0):

Use text-align center to center your paragraph

```
.center p
{
     text-align: center;
}
```